# how to call main activity code in a recycler view that is inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i have already got all things ready set-up my fragment communication, but my only problem is how can i make the recycler view `itemVitem.setOnClickListener` call the overridden interface method in the main activity so i can get that data and create an intent with to go to detail activity or update detail fragment for dual-pane layout, more explanation is provided with comments on code below.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListFragment.Listener {

// the method to be called when an item in recycler view is clicked
// so i can pass this data to DetailFragment
@Override
public void listener(String firstName, String lastName) {
    DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
    detailFragment.updateText(firstName, lastName);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvFirstName;
    public TextView tvLastName;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvFirstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_first_name);
        tvLastName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_last_name);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // how to call the "listener()" method in main activity
            }
        });
    }
```

the fragment containing the recycler view

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "ListFragment"; 

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

// fragment communication interface
public interface Listener {
    void listener(String firstName, String lastName);
}

private Listener listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        this.listener = (Listener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}

public ListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    // some dummy data to fill the recycler view
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    users.add(new User("hiwa", "jalal"));
    users.add(new User("mohammed", "abdullah"));


    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(users, getActivity());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

}
}
```

DetailFragment

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {


private TextView tvFirstName;
private TextView tvLastName;

public DetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    tvFirstName = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_frag_first_name);
    tvLastName = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_frag_last_name);
}

// update the details fragment views
public void updateText(String firstName, String lastName) {
    tvFirstName.setText(firstName);
    tvLastName.setText(lastName);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `listener` to your `RecyclerViewAdapter` and use this to call the callback

```
recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(users, getActivity(), listener);
```

Update `RecyclerViewAdapter` like below

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter {
   private Listener mListener;

   ....

   public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<User> users, Context context, Listener listener) {
       ....

       mListener = listener;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       ....

       holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.listener(first_name. last_name);
           }
        });

       ....
   }

   ....
}
```

Comment: thank you this worked, data got passed to activity but the problem is when i call `detailFragment.updateText(firstName, lastName);` i get null pointer exception on it's widget even though i initialized them in detailFragment like this 


` @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        tvFirstName = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_frag_first_name);
        tvLastName = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_frag_last_name);
    } `

Comment: Add details of your `DetailFragment `

Comment: Probably that is different issue related to `Fragment`. To keep these thread clean you should ask another question with `Fragment` details. Please accept this and post another. Thanks

Comment: i already updated the question but okay will do that, thanks.

Comment: The crash is due to tvFirstName ,tvLastName is not initialized yet.
You are creating fragment and just after creating it, you are calling the update method.
which don't guarantee that views are initialized.
Pass data inside bundle. then use it .

Comment: @KishanMaurya, Is that the reason here to crash?

Comment: @KishanMaurya unfortunately, it didn't fix it.

Comment: Add fragment transaction also.
Adding fragment to activity container code is missing.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman i added the question as you asked, here is the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59145291/11385677

Comment: @KishanMaurya i added it through XML!

Answer (score 1):

Create Method in adapter class.

```
private Listener mListener;
public void setListener(Listener listener){
mListener = listener
}

public void removeListener(){
mListener = null;
}
```

Inside Fragment class, set listener like below.

```
recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(users, getActivity());
recyclerViewAdapter.setListener(listener);
```

In ViewHolder

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.listener(first_name. last_name);
           }
        });
```

Also in OnDestroy or OnDestroyView() of fragment, call

```
removeListener() to avoid memory leak.
```

Comment: Please avoid to `copy-paste` similar answer. If you have different approach, then only post this otherwise appreciate other answer. Hope you understand. Thanks