# android fragment view throw null pointer exception even after being initialized in onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments

here i have a fragment interaction, where if recycler view item get clicked it passed data to `MainActivity` and then `MainActivity` call `DetailFragment.updateText()` method to update it's view but the views are not initialized even though i did that in `onViewCreated()`, if `DetailFragment.updateText()` is getting called before views are initialized then how can i make sure they get called after views have been initialized.
* note i added the `DetailFragment` to a `DetailActivity` through XML fragment tag, and the same for `ListFragment` and `MainActivity`

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListFragment.Listener {

// the method to be called when an item in recycler view is clicked
// so i can pass this data to DetailFragment

@Override
public void listenerMethod(String firstName, String lastName) {
    DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
    detailFragment.updateText(firstName, lastName);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

ListFragment

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "ListFragment";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

// fragment communication interface
public interface Listener {
    void listenerMethod(String firstName, String lastName);
}

private Listener listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        this.listener = (Listener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}

public ListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    // some dummy data to fill the recycler view
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    users.add(new User("hiwa", "jalal"));
    users.add(new User("mohammed", "abdullah"));


    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(users, getActivity(), listener);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
}
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<User> userList;
private Context context;
private ListFragment.Listener listener;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<User> userList, Context context, ListFragment.Listener listener) {
    this.userList = userList;
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_row
            , parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    User user = userList.get(position);
    holder.tvFirstName.setText(user.getFirstName());
    holder.tvLastName.setText(user.getLastName());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvFirstName;
    public TextView tvLastName;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvFirstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_first_name);
        tvLastName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_last_name);

 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          User user = userList.get(getAdapterPosition);

            listener.listenerMethod(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName());
        }
    });


    }
}
}
```

DetailFragment

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView tvFirstName;
private TextView tvLastName;

public DetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    tvFirstName = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_frag_first_name);
    tvLastName = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_frag_last_name);
}

// update the details fragment views
public void updateText(String firstName, String lastName) {
    tvFirstName.setText(firstName);
    tvLastName.setText(lastName);
}
```

}

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_list"
        android:name="com.example.peacewithfragments.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_detail

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailsActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailsActivity_fragment_container"
        android:name="com.example.peacewithfragments.DetailFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have any fragment container in your `MainActivity` to add `DetailFragment `? If so, then add those part also

Comment: i added it through XML.

Comment: You can't access `DetailFragment`'s view directly instantiating it, you have to attach it to `MainActivity` first

Comment: Add more details of your `MainActivity` about Fragment transaction to add those fragment

Comment: so should i added that fragment too in the main_activty.xml

Comment: that's my full code of MainActivity

Comment: Then post your xml too

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman okay got it, i just didn't want to make the question get big.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203486/discussion-between-md-asaduzzaman-and-hiwa-doski).

Comment: Okay got it, i sent you a message there.

Comment: Check my updated answer in `MainActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly access `DetailFragment` from your `MainActivity` as it's not part of `MainActivity`. So, first you have to navigate to `DetailActivity` and then access `DetailFragment`. Check below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListFragment.Listener {

    private DetailFragment detailFragment;

    @Override
    public void listenerMethod(String firstName, String lastName) {
        if(detailFragment != null) {
            detailFragment.updateText(firstName, lastName);
        } else {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra("FirstName", firstName);
            detailIntent.putExtra("LastName", lastName);

            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View view = findViewById(R.id.tablet_detail_container);
        if (view != null) {
            detailFragment = new DetailFragment();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


            transaction.add(R.id.tablet_detail_container, detailFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `DetailsActivity` accept those extra and pass it to `DetailFragment` like below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    ...

    String firstName = getIntent().getStringExtra("FirstName");
    String lastName = getIntent().getStringExtra("LastName");

    DetailFragment detailFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailsActivity_fragment_container);

    if(detailFragment != null)
        detailFragment.updateText(firstName, lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You create a new instance of the DetialsFragment every time you trigger the method of your listener. If you have defined the fragment in your layout xml, you must get the correct instance of the fragment from the fragmentmanager (or supportFragmentManager as you are using AppCompatActivity.

```
@Override
public void listenerMethod(String firstName, String lastName) {

  // find the fragment by its id, sometihng like that
  // id is the fragments id you defined in the layout xml
  DetailsFragment detailFragment = (DetailsFragment)supportFragmentManager.findFragementById(R.id.frag_details);
  detailFragment.updateText(firstName, lastName);
}
```